# Selenium popup support

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Please give me an example java code to open a popup and move RC control to popup. 
is there any way to come back on main window after checking some element on popup window.

I have few questions on this as selenium always need windowid  to get control over popup.

1-What is the best way to get the windowid of any popup.

2-Should i have to search it in view sources of base page.

3-is it necessary that we must get the windowid of the each & every popup in the view source of the page. if not so what will be work-around.

4-Is window id present in any java-script function? if so ,there is one example 
I didn’t get Window id of popup

script language="javascript"

begin

function popup(){

window.open('URL/to/popup.html','PopupName','toolbar=0,location=0,
status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,width=345,height=400');
}

// end

/script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will definitely help you. [Handling Popups](http://vinoygeorge.wordpress.com/selenium/selenium-rc-and-pop-up-handling/)

Hope this helps

Comment: It is great help vaman. i have edited my question ,please resolve my queries. Thanks again